# Unable to send email via Office 365 C# client library

Tags: c#, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to send an email with the Office 365 C# client library. I've successfully performed other operations with it, i.e. getting a folder and getting messages, but am unable to send an email.

I'm using a MailHelper class provided in a Microsoft sample. This is the method:

```cs
internal async Task<String> ComposeAndSendMailAsync(string subject,
                                                            string bodyContent,
                                                            string recipients)
        {
            // The identifier of the composed and sent message.
            string newMessageId = string.Empty;

            // Prepare the recipient list
            var toRecipients = new List<Recipient>();
            string[] splitter = { ";" };
            var splitRecipientsString = recipients.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string recipient in splitRecipientsString)
            {
                toRecipients.Add(new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = recipient.Trim(),
                        Name = recipient.Trim(),
                    },
                });
            }

            // Prepare the draft message.
            var draft = new Message
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.HTML,
                    Content = bodyContent
                },
                ToRecipients = toRecipients
            };

            try
            {
                // Make sure we have a reference to the Outlook Services client.
                var outlookClient = await AuthenticationHelper.GetOutlookClientAsync("Mail");

                //Send the mail.
                await outlookClient.Me.SendMailAsync(draft, true);

                return draft.Id;
            }

            //Catch any exceptions related to invalid OData.
            catch (Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException ode)
            {

                throw new Exception("We could not send the message: " + ode.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("We could not send the message: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

My arguments are not null and seem to be correct. The error I'm getting is: "**Cannot read the request body.**".

I've made sure my application is registered with the right permissions so I'm at a loss. Does anyone know what's going on with my code?

Comment: Try changing the `BodyType.HTML` to `BodyType.Text`

Comment: I had already given that a go without any change. It's complaining about the request body which I don't think I have control over since the library handles it. The ContentType above is just for the Body of the Message.

Comment: Well, I don't use the Client library, I use the REST-API, and I only got this error when I forgot to change the content-type to `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing a Fiddler trace of the request and check the Content-Type header.

Comment: I tried that, however, it looks like something is blocking my authentication flow when I try to use Fiddler with it.